# Migrating Ubuntu Server to new system

Tags: ubuntu, debian

An issue came up with our current Ubuntu box that requires it to be moved to a new box. Currently, there is over 4TB of data stored in the system, so installing a fresh install, migrating data and configuration may become a little tedious.

My question is, since ubuntu server runs headless, can I swap it to a new box easily. Im aware that the etho port will have to be reconfigured due to ubuntu caching the mac address.

I have done this with other linux systems in the past. Not too sure on the ubuntu dependencies tho.

The old system C2Q with 6GB ram. New system i7 16GB ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the data all stored on one hard drive or over multiple hard drives ?
Is LVM Configured to map to labels ?

If it's only one hard drive, it's a simple matter of clearing the udev rule before unplugging the hard drive and swapping it over to the new machine.

If there's multiple hard drives, then you'll need to make sure they are mounted / mapped properly when plugged into the new machine. Apart from that, it *should* be a matter of simple plug and play.

Comment: Mutile HDs, (2) One primary that Rsync's backups to the second.